# How can a+b be NOT equal to b+a?

Tags: numbers, logic, equals

Our professor said that in computer logic it's important when you add a number to another so a+b and b+a are not always equal. 
Though,I couldn't find an example of when they would be different and why they won't be equal. 
I think it would have to do something with bits but then again ,I'm not sure.

Comment: Is there any more context to this?

Comment: No ,not really. It's just that,unfortunately.

Comment: you should ask your professor and get back to us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obscure possibility is if one or other of a or b is a high-definition timer value - ticks since program start.

Due to the cpu cycle(s) consumed to pop one of the values before addition, it's possible the sum could be different dependant on the order.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't share a lot of context it sounds as if your professor did not elaborate on that or you missed something.

In the case that he was talking about logic in general, he could have meant that the behavior of the `+` operator depends on how you define it.

Example: The definition `(+) a b := if (a==0) then 5 else 0` results in a `+` operator which is not associative, e.g. 1 + 0 would be 0 but 0 + 1 would be 5. There are many programming languages that allow this redefinition (overwriting) of standard operators.

But with the context you share, this is all speculative.

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility is if `a` and `b` are expressions with side effects. E.g.

```
int x = 0;

int a() {
    x += 1;
    return x;
}

int b() {
    return x;
}
```

`a() + b()` will return 2 and `b() + a()` will return 1 (both from initial state).

Or it could be that `a` or `b` are `NaN`, in which case even `a == a` is false. Though this one isn't connected with "when you add a number to another".